# switch application and assigning them to instance

Tags: c#, processor, user32

I'm having problems with switching application and assigning them to a variable. This is what I have so far.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool b);

Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel");
foreach (Process proc in procs)
{
    SwitchToThisWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, false);
}
```

In the end I want to assign that Excel window to be assigned to xlApp. I tried:

 `xlAppl = SwitchToThisWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, false);` but obviously this won't work because the interface is a void. I tried looking at `GetActiveWindow` I was thinking of getting active window and assign it but it's return value is not an Object it's IntPtr.
Is there a way out of this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. What you want to assign? What is the return value you're expecting?

Comment: If proc.MainWindowHandle has the reference to the Excel window, why not `IntPtr excel = proc.MainWindowHandle;`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things I want to point out about what you have so far:

1. For SwitchToThisWindow MSDN states - [This function is not intended for general use. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.]. So I personally wouldn't use that one if I were you.
2. Your Process.GetProcessByName call is going to return all excel processes. Then you're going to try to bring each one to the foreground. Only the last one of course will actually be in the foreground, since they can't all be in the foreground. You should probably decide on a more accurate way of choosing which one you want.
3. You are assuming that MainWindowHandle is not IntPtr.Zero which is not a valid assumption in all cases. MainWindowHandle will only have a value once there is a visible window that has been rendered.

If I were you I'd try using the [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetActiveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646311(v=vs.85).aspx) APIs instead.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(
    IntPtr hWnd
    );

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(
    IntPtr hWnd
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the solution. Pretty simple here is the answer if anyone else is looking for this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```